# How to check if the input is a regular dataframe or groupby object?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking for a function that can check if the input object is a dataframe or a goubby object.

```
def fun(input_object):
    if is_goupby_object():
        // Doing something on goupby object
    else:
        // Otherwise do something on the dataframe
```

Comment: can you explain bit more... what you want to do... as I'm seeing.... your code might be your solution, then what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
def is_goupby_object(obj):
    try:
        if(obj.ngroups > 0):
            return True
    except:
        return False

if(is_goupby_object(df_groupby)):
    // Doing something on gouupby object
elif isinstance(dfObj, pd.DataFrame):
    // Otherwise do something on the dataframe
else:
   // not a groupby or df object
```